# How to change values of Microsoft Access database from java?

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc

I am trying to make an app that changes certain values of an MS-Access database. I am not trying to add new lines or anything. My problem is that I get a `net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::5.0.0-SNAPSHOT attempt to assign to non-updatable column` error. The current code I'm using is

```
    try {
        sql = "SELECT * FROM MtnRoads";

        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C://Users//anyGenericProgrammer//Documents//Database1.accdb");

        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        result.updateString(aNumber, aString);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        errCode.setText(e.toString());
        System.out.println(e);
    }`
```

I have looked at this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31435940/using-update-statement-with-ms-access-2010-database-in-java#) to figure out how to even update the lines in the first place, however the example that is used in extremely confusing. Is there any way to make this work without throwing errors? (I am using `javax.swing.JFrame` library, errCode is a JLable.)

Comment: This might help: [net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: attempt to assign to non-updatable column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28518989/net-ucanaccess-jdbc-ucanaccesssqlexception-attempt-to-assign-to-non-updatable-c)

Comment: @Rene, the answer for that question is giving me the error `ucanaccess cannot be resolved or is not a field` and `UcanaccessConnection.prepare...`, which I found, is giving me a "cannot make static reference..." error.